# Some files send on a HLS Server using Http Put request are partially uploaded

Tags: c++, http-live-streaming, http-put

I have to upload audio chunks continuously on a HLS Server as a part of my project. I am able to upload chunks sucessfully using HTTP Put method with wininet API in C++ using following code.

```
bool CHTTP::HttpPut(char *szFile,int fileType)
{   

    bool bErrorFlag = false;
    if(m_hInternet == NULL)
    {
        int retStatus = OpenHTTPSession();
        if(retStatus < 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    char szPostURL[256];
    INTERNET_BUFFERS BufferIn = {0};
    DWORD dwBytesRead;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten;
    BYTE pBuffer[350000]; 
    BOOL bRead, bRet;
    static int flag = 1;
    BufferIn.dwStructSize = sizeof( INTERNET_BUFFERS );

    char szLocalFilePath[256];
    if(fileType == AUDIO_CHUNK)
        sprintf(szLocalFilePath,"%s/%s",m_strFilePath,szFile);
    else
        strcpy(szLocalFilePath,szFile);

    int iFileSize = 0;

    if(fileType == AUDIO_CHUNK)
    {
        strcpy(szPostURL,m_strPostPath);
        strcat(szPostURL,"/");
        strcat(szPostURL,szFile);
    }
    else if(fileType == M3U8)
        strcpy(szPostURL,m_szM3U8FileToPost);
    else if(fileType == AUTO_M3U8)
        strcpy(szPostURL,m_szM3U8AutoPost);

    DWORD dwFlags = 
        INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION |
        INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES |
        INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE |
        INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI |
        INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD |INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;

    m_hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(m_hHttpSession, (const char*)"PUT",szPostURL, "HTTP/1.1",NULL , (const char**)"*/*\0",dwFlags, 1);

    if(m_hRequest==NULL) 
    {
        bErrorFlag = true;
        CloseHTTPSession();
        return bErrorFlag;
    }
    else
    {
        bErrorFlag = false;
    }

    int num_of_try = 0;
    while(num_of_try < 3)
    {
        char logDump[1000];
        num_of_try++;
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile (szLocalFilePath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
            NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            bErrorFlag = true;
            break;
        }
        else if(!m_bLogFlagCreateErr)
        {
            m_bLogFlagCreateErr = true;
            sprintf(logDump,"CreateFile success %s",szFile);
            WriteLog(mLogFile,logDump);
            bErrorFlag = false;
        }

        BufferIn.dwBufferTotal = GetFileSize (hFile, NULL);
        iFileSize = BufferIn.dwBufferTotal;
        if(!HttpSendRequestEx( m_hRequest, &BufferIn, NULL, HSR_INITIATE, 0))
        {
            bErrorFlag = true;
            m_bLogFlagSend = false;
            sprintf(logDump,"Error on HttpSendRequestEx %lu %s",GetLastError(),szFile);
            WriteLog(mLogFile,logDump);

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            bErrorFlag = false;
            sprintf(logDump,"HttpSendRequest success %s",szFile);
            WriteLog(mLogFile,logDump);
        }
        DWORD sum = 0;
        int size = 0;
        do
        {
            bRead = ReadFile (hFile, pBuffer,iFileSize,
                &dwBytesRead, NULL);

            if(dwBytesRead != iFileSize)
            {
                sprintf(logDump,"dwBytesRead %d iFileSize %d %s",dwBytesRead,iFileSize,szFile);
                WriteLog(mLogFile,logDump);
            }

            if(dwBytesRead > 0)
            {
                bRet=InternetWriteFile( m_hRequest, pBuffer, dwBytesRead,
                    &dwBytesWritten);

                while(dwBytesRead < dwBytesWritten && bRet)
                {
                    sprintf(logDump,"dwBytesRead %d dwBytesWritten %d %s",dwBytesRead,dwBytesWritten,szFile);
                    WriteLog(mLogFile,logDump);
                    bRet=InternetWriteFile( m_hRequest, pBuffer+dwBytesWritten, dwBytesRead - dwBytesWritten ,&dwBytesWritten);
                }
                if(!bRet)
                {
                    int error = GetLastError();
                    sprintf(logDump,"InternetWriteFile %lu %s",error,szFile);
                    WriteLog(mLogFile,logDump);
                    bErrorFlag = true;
                    break;
                }
                else 
                {
                    sprintf(logDump,"InternetWriteFile buffer success %s",szFile);
                    WriteLog(mLogFile,logDump);
                    bErrorFlag = false;

                }
            }
        }
        while (dwBytesRead == iFileSize);
        CloseHandle (hFile);

        if(!HttpEndRequest(m_hRequest, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            int error = GetLastError();
            if(error != 12032)
            {
                sprintf(logDump,"HttpEndRequest %lu %s",error,szFile);
                WriteLog(mLogFile,logDump)
                bErrorFlag = true;
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                bErrorFlag = true;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            sprintf(logDump,"HttpEndRequest success %s",szFile);
            WriteLog(mLogFile,logDump);

            DWORD dwCode, dwCodeSize; 
            dwCodeSize = sizeof(DWORD);
            if(!HttpQueryInfo(m_hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, &dwCode, &dwCodeSize, NULL))
            {
                int error = GetLastError();
                char tmp[256];
                sprintf(tmp,"HttpQueryfails %d %s",error, szFile);
                WriteLog(mLogFile,tmp);

            }
            else
            {
                if(dwCode != 201 && dwCode != 204)
                {
                    char tmp[256];
                    sprintf(tmp,"dwcode %d is not 201 or 204 %s",dwCode,szFile);
                    WriteLog(mLogFile,tmp);
                    bErrorFlag = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            bErrorFlag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    CloseHTTPSession();
    return bErrorFlag;
}
```

Most of the times chunks uploaded are of full size. Randomly chunks uploaded on server are not of full size as shown in following image.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhdwK.png)

In such case I am not getting any error messages, even dwBytesWritten returned by InternetWriteFile function is also correct. I am unable to understand what should I do to solve it. Any help in this regard is appreciated.